# Powershell loop for splitting mutiple txt files into seperate files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm having an issue looping through all files in the directory and splitting it according to the field "[IMPORT]"

Directory: \C\users$\Pepe\Desktop\TestInfoFolder

I have the following two files in the directory:
TestingInfo1.txt
TestingInfo2.txt

They look like this:
TestingInfo1.txt

```
[IMPORT]
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
[IMPORT]
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

TestingInfo2.txt

```
[IMPORT]
21
22
23
24
25
```

Desired Results would be 3 separate files split the string "[IMPORT]" this is included in the files.

Results 1:

```
[IMPORT]
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Result 2:

```
[IMPORT]
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

Results 3:

```
[IMPORT]
21
22
23
24
25
```

Current Code:

```
$Path = "\\C\users$\Pepe\Desktop\TestInfoFolder"
Get-ChildItem $Path | foreach-object {
   $InputFile = $_.FullName
   $Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($InputFile)
   $N = 1

While (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
   if ($Line -match "[IMPORT]") {
       $OutputFile = $matches[0] + $N + ".txt"
       $N++
   }

   Add-Content (Join-Path $Path $OutputFile) $Line
   }
}
```

The issue with the current query is that it appends the results of TestingInfo2.txt in the results of Results 1. Please let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: Because all your imports are the same word, and it starts `$N=1` at the start of each file. Put `$N=1` before the `Get-ChildItem` line, and it will just count forever.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are your friend here. This should give you all instances of your IMPORT sequence from all files in $Path:

```
ls $Path | cat | select-string -AllMatches "(\[IMPORT\][\s*\d+]+)" | % {$_.Matches.Value}
```

Comment: Ah, you edited the question; this solution will not work now that I see that the digits are on separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something similar to Jon Dechiro, but I would gather all text into one variable as a multi-line string, and then split that into chunks that include everything from one `[IMPORT]` up to the next one (or the end of the file), then output each item in a `FOR` loop:

```
$Path = "C:\Users\Pepe\Desktop\TestInfoFolder"
$InputText = (Get-Content "$Path\*.txt" -Raw) -join "`r`n"
$SplitText = $InputText -split "(?s)(\[IMPORT].*?)(?=\[IMPORT]|$)"|?{$_}
New-Item -Path $Path\Output -ItemType Directory -Force|Out-Null
For($i=0;$i -le $SplitText.Count;$i++){
    $SplitText[$i] | Set-Content "$Path\Output\Results$($i+1).txt" -Force
}
```

That will create a folder "Output" in the Path, and save the results there.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
$SourcePath = "C:\Users\jon_dechiro\Desktop\Test"
$OutputPath = "C:\Temp"
$Count = 1
foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -File))
{
    $FileRawContents = Get-Content $File.FullName -Raw
    foreach ($Import in ($FileRawContents -split '\[IMPORT\]'))
    {
        if ($Import -match '\d')
        {
            $ImportEdited = $Import -replace '\n', "`r`n"
            "[IMPORT]$ImportEdited" | Out-File "$OutputPath\Results$Count.txt"
            $Count++
        }
    }
}
```

That opens each file and splits by [IMPORT] and then sends each result to the output files as you indicated. Of course change the $SourcePath and $OutputPath variables to be what you need.

Comment: this works great, but the resulting file doesn't insert a carriage return after each line that it reads in. How would I go about adding in a carriage return after line it reads in? For example if would read [IMPORT]CR LF

Comment: Checking with Notepad++ on my system shows there is a CR LF after each line in the output created by the code I posted. Is that not the case on your system?

Comment: In the original files I have they only contain the "data line"LF and I want it to insert it so that it say "data line"CR LF. Anyway I can do that?

Comment: I edited my test files to remove the CR and only have LF. I edited the answer to include a step to replace LF with CR LF. That works on my system. See if that works for you.

Comment: That worked great. Thank you so much. This gives me a great place to work from. I can't thank you enough.